# Dataset - Running custom tool MSDataSetGenerator - out of memory error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dataset

At my new job I have been given a task to fix a broken web-site left by the previous developer.
I got the issues fixed to the point where it compiles and runs. 
This was running using .Net 4.7.2

When I changed the target to .Net 4.8 and compile I get the following error.

> Custom tool error: Failed to generate code.
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   SharedDll D:\SHARED\trunk\SharedDll\DataSetPortal.xsd

So I went into the project `SharedDll` and right clicked the `DataSetPortal.xsd` and clicked `Run Custom Tool`.
I get message box popped up saying

> The custom tool 'MSDataSetGenerator' failed. Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

PC has 32GB Ram.
Project is targeting .Net 4.8 64bit

**Update**
I have since re-targeted .Net 4.7.2 and tried running the tool and I get the same error so it is not .Net 4.8 related.

Comment: Without any code (and exact specification of all version numbers etc) there is little chance of answer.

Comment: You could (should) start by creating a [mcve]

Comment: @HenkHolterman All version numbers of what? I have a library project targeting .net 4.8

Comment: @HenkHolterman Normally I would post code but the issue is coming from the MSDataSetGenerator so there is no code. What I am trying to get out is why is this tool generating the error when it runs.

Comment: And what version that generator?

Comment: @HenkHolterman how do I find that out?